# Finding some errors in my "IEEE conference paper" after presentation but before publication

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, errors-erratum, ieee

Two days ago, I presented `my accepted paper in an IEEE conference`. While I am presenting, I noticed that I really made 3 mistakes in the notations! I don't really know why I didn't make attention for that before! For example, in the first place, I wrote `lambda` instead of `alpha`. In other place, I forgot to put an absolute value to the variable used. In the third place, I forgot a parenthesis for a group of variables. The problem is that in this part (very mathematical part), I have a lot of mathematical notations, and so I made these errors.

My errors do not affect neither the results nor the conclusion since while I am citing another paper and writing some of its equations in my paper, I made these errors. So I think the reader will detect these errors when he reads the cited paper (it is very embarrassing for me when the author of the paper I cited sees that I made errors in his equations! very embarrassing). I think an interesting reader to my paper will only consider that these errors are due to the lack of enough revisions before the camera-ready deadline, I hope! (what do you think?). I am really very sad because in this case some researchers will consider me as a "careless writer".

The paper is not yet published online, but I have already presented it (two days ago) in the conference. So I am wondering if it is still possible to contact the committee and tell them about the errors? do you think they can provide me a chance to send them a correct version? is it still possible?

BTW I have submitted the corrected version on ArXiv and researchgate. But I don't know if the researchers will make attention that the errors are corrected on ArXiv for example? do you think the reasearchers mostly read papers on ArXiv rather than reading the official versions present in IEEE Xplore?

Comment: How did this work out for you in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's worthy to try, there's no shame in doing it.

Contact them and tell that you have found some typos which you would like to correct before publication. Attach to the email the corrected version and another pdf with the highlighted changes, where they will be able to easily spot the minor issues you found.

Comment: This, or just a list of the corrections required, since it sounds like there are only a few and quite minor. And to the OP, I wouldn't worry about looking careless; we all make mistakes of this sort, and if they got past peer review then clearly they weren't too blatant.

Comment: @The Doctor and Geoffrey Brent thank you for your comments. I am just afraid if I tell the committee about the errors, they probably withdraw  my paper I think, no?

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent, I think the reviewers did not make attention for these errors. I had a very interesting results and beautiful conclusion. So I think they were affected by the conclusion. We also cannot trust all reviewers even if my paper is accepted in a very well known conference. Some reviewers read the paper at the last time, unfortunately.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent what is the abbreviation of ''OP'' you mentioned? Do you think I can contact ''conference-ops@ieee.org''  or the committee ?

Comment: @Christina "OP" = "original poster (in the thread)", i.e. you; sorry for the confusion there. I'm not familiar with IEEE so I'll leave it to others to comment on IEEE specifics, but I would be astounded if anybody wanted to withdraw a paper for a few minor notational errors. If your conclusions were interesting and the errors don't change that conclusion, then it's still a good paper.

Comment: Listen to @Geoffrey, they will never withdrawn your paper due to the minor corrections you are proposing.

Comment: Thank you @TheDoctor I will try and keep you informed about the news!

Comment: Good luck with it. :)

Comment: I sent them a mail since last Saturday but they did not answer yet. I hope I will get an answer from them soon.

Comment: @Christina how did this work out for you in the end?

Comment: @Stumbler unfortunately my paper has been published on IEEE with some errors. But I have corrected them on ArXiv and HAL. Are you facing the same problem?

Comment: @Christina yes. I'm concerned that if I point out the error, I may run the risk of IEEE deciding not to publish. The error does not change the conclusion in any way, but means some of the figures I quote will otherwise not match up with my later work.

Comment: If you have already presented your paper in the conference, so it is too late to contact the technical program committee for changes. You can just correct the mistakes and submit the corrected version on ArXiv and HAL.

Comment: If you are targeting to write a journal paper or other conference paper for your work, you can point out the error to the authors and explain that in a footnote and add a reference to your paper that contains the error. I became sick for some days when I discovered that I made some errors. But then the lesson I learned was to revise the paper very well before any last submission. I was at Yale university and it was hard for me to accept such errors in my paper. But look everybody make errors even at top universities. So don't worry I am sure your future papers will be much better.